# Trying to make a toggle type button in pygame. Having an issue

Tags: python, pygame

Alright, so the issue here is that upon reviving the click, the first condition is satisfied, and the variable is set to true. Immediately after, the event is like... still going on or whatever, and the variable being false satisfies the second condition, which immediately resets the variable to true. Any ideas on how to resolve this sort of thing?

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():    
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
        x, y = event.pos
        if TutorialOn == True:
            if x >= 25 and x <= 175 and y >= 350 and y<= 450:
                TutorialOn = False 
        if TutorialOn == False:
            if x >= 25 and x <= 175 and y >= 350 and y<= 450:
                TutorialOn = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `elif` statement. `elif` means "else if". If the first condition turns out to be true, then your second condition won't be tested at all and then you won't have this issue.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():    
if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
    x, y = event.pos
    if TutorialOn == True:
        if x >= 25 and x <= 175 and y >= 350 and y<= 450:
            TutorialOn = False 
    elif TutorialOn == False:
        if x >= 25 and x <= 175 and y >= 350 and y<= 450:
            TutorialOn = True
```

Also, another thing to note is that your logic can be further simplified. You don't need to do `if TutorialOn == True:`. The `if` statement does that for you. And if `TutorialOn` happens to not be true, then there is only one other possible boolean value for it, False! Therefore, the second condition will not need to be tested and you can just use a simple `else` statement with no condition at all. When you use an `else` statement with no condition, the block of code that follows it will immediately execute if the previous `if` or `elif` statement turned out to be False. See the following simplification of your code:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():    
if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
    x, y = event.pos
    if TutorialOn:
        if x >= 25 and x <= 175 and y >= 350 and y<= 450:
            TutorialOn = False 
    else:
        if x >= 25 and x <= 175 and y >= 350 and y<= 450:
            TutorialOn = True
```

As @Paulo pointed out in the comments, there is an even further simplification you can make. Since all you are doing is flipping the boolean value of `TutorialOn` if the condition `x >= 25 and x <= 175 and y >= 350 and y<= 450` happens to be true, you can use a simple `not` statement to "toggle" it.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():    
if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
    x, y = event.pos
    if x >= 25 and x <= 175 and y >= 350 and y<= 450:
        TutorialOn = not TutorialOn
```

Comment: Wow i feel dumb. Thanks.

Comment: It could be further simplified to: `if 25 <= x <= 175 and 350 <= y <= 450: tutorialOn = not tutorialOn`. But I like your answer because I suppose `elif` and `else` are the most helpful lessons here.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Yup, a boolean toggle could be used. Very good point.

Comment: I saw you added my suggestion, but you shouldn't have `if TutorialOn:`, so it also toggles if it's `False`.

Comment: You can even further simplify the condition using a `Rect` and the `collidespoint` function.